# Find equal side lengths for isosceles triangle from middle angle and area?

Tags: triangles, area, angle

I know that this is a really easy question, but I am looking for the answer to this question:

> The area of this isosceles triangle is 5cm squared.
>
> The angle ABC is 22 degrees.
>
> Work out the lengths of the two equal sides of the triangle

Thanks

[Here is an image of the question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sugE6.png)

Comment: Which two sides are equal?

Comment: If $22^\circ$ is the included angle of those equal sides, then let $r$ be the equal sides, and then we have $\dfrac12r^2\sin(22^\circ)=5$.

Comment: can you post a picture please?

Comment: Otherwise, the included angle of the equal sides would be $180^\circ-22^\circ-22^\circ=136^\circ$, so we would have $\dfrac12r^2\sin(136^\circ)=5$.

Comment: I have posted a photo

Comment: I know the area, I want to work out x (the two sides with equal length)

Comment: @kenny It is an isosceles triangle, so the two sides either side of the angle are equal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from $$5cm^2=\frac{1}{2}x^2\sin(22^{\circ})$$ we get $$x=\sqrt{\frac{10cm^2}{\sin(22^{\circ})}}$$ now you can take a calculator.

Comment: I will try that now...

Comment: So x=5.2? is that right?

Comment: yes it is $$5.166688651887216543546753918323821954845281114471415318333742588216703336294167483471276050440784083$$